# Error running "meteor run ios"

Tags: macos, cordova, meteor

I'm trying to build a mobile version of my Meteor app for the first time. I'm following the instructions in:

https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html

When I attempt to run `meteor run ios`, I get the following error:

```
 meteor run ios
[[[[[ ~/github/bowfolios/bowfolios/app ]]]]]  

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
WARNING: Attempting to install plugin cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.2.1, but it should have a minimum version of 2.2.3 to ensure
         compatibility with the current platform versions. Installing the minimum version for convenience, but you should adjust
         your dependencies.
WARNING: Attempting to install plugin cordova-plugin-splashscreen@4.0.1, but it should have a minimum version of 4.0.3 to ensure
         compatibility with the current platform versions. Installing the minimum version for convenience, but you should adjust
         your dependencies.
W20171002-16:00:12.543(-10)? (STDERR) Note: you are using a pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt.
W20171002-16:00:12.641(-10)? (STDERR) While this implementation will work correctly, it is known to be
W20171002-16:00:12.642(-10)? (STDERR) approximately three times slower than the native implementation.
W20171002-16:00:12.644(-10)? (STDERR) In order to use the native implementation instead, run
W20171002-16:00:12.646(-10)? (STDERR)         
W20171002-16:00:12.648(-10)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save bcrypt
W20171002-16:00:12.651(-10)? (STDERR)         
W20171002-16:00:12.652(-10)? (STDERR) in the root directory of your application.
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/     
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:         

   While running Cordova app for platform iOS with options --emulator:
   Error: Command failed:                     
   /Users/philipjohnson/github/bowfolios/bowfolios/app/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/run --emulator
   Device type "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.undefined" could not be found.
   at ChildProcess.exitCallback (/tools/utils/processes.js:151:23)
   at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:12)
   => awaited here:
   at Function.Promise.await
   (/Users/philipjohnson/.meteor/packages/less/.2.7.9.1fv9ffj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileLessBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:35:12)
   at CordovaProject.runCommands (/tools/cordova/project.js:715:22)
   at CordovaProject.run$ (/tools/cordova/project.js:261:10)
   at tryCatch
   (/Users/philipjohnson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_1.tt3xct++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
   at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke]
   (/Users/philipjohnson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_1.tt3xct++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:337:22)
   at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next]
   (/Users/philipjohnson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_1.tt3xct++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:96:21)
   at tryCatch
   (/Users/philipjohnson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_1.tt3xct++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
   at invoke
   (/Users/philipjohnson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_1.tt3xct++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:139:20)
   at
   /Users/philipjohnson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_1.tt3xct++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:184:11
   at callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
   (/Users/philipjohnson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_1.tt3xct++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:183:16)
   at AsyncIterator.enqueue
   (/Users/philipjohnson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_1.tt3xct++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:206:13)
   at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next]
   (/Users/philipjohnson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_1.tt3xct++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:96:21)
   at Object.runtime.async
   (/Users/philipjohnson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_1.tt3xct++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:226:14)
   at
   /Users/philipjohnson/.meteor/packages/less/.2.7.9.1fv9ffj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileLessBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:32:39

/Users/philipjohnson/.meteor/packages/less/.2.7.9.1fv9ffj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileLessBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:190
      throw error;
      ^
undefined
 => awaited here:
    at Function.Promise.await (/Users/philipjohnson/.meteor/packages/less/.2.7.9.1fv9ffj++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileLessBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:35:12)
    at /tools/cordova/runner.js:98:17
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:271:13
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:264:29
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:262:18
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:253:23
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.capture (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:252:19)
    at CordovaRunner.startRunTargets (/tools/cordova/runner.js:97:37)
    at [object Object]._.extend._runOnce (/tools/runners/run-app.js:772:21)
    at [object Object]._.extend._fiber (/tools/runners/run-app.js:885:28)
    at /tools/runners/run-app.js:412:1234:
```

I'm running Meteor 1.5.2.1 on MacOS 10.12.6.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed Xcode? https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#installing-prerequisites-ios

Comment: Yes:

    [~]-> gcc --version
    Configured with: --
    prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-
    include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
    Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
    Thread model: posix
    InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Answer (score 1):

My googling was off yesterday. Today I found the resolution:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/9126